# Section numbers behind section title

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm an absolute newbie to TeX. I'm trying to get the section numbers of a section to be at the end of the title. In other words, something like "Question 4.2". Instead I get "4.2 Question 4.2" which is not great. Also, the numbers should follow with indentation. For example:

```
Question 4.2
  4.2.1 ....
  4.2.2 ....
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the format of the sections using the `titlesec` package.
The indention of the subsections can also be done with it. However, I'm not 100% sure what you exactly mean with *Also, the numbers should follow with indentation.*

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries}
{Question\ \thesection}{2.3ex plus .2ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{2em}{*1}{*1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{X}

\section{A}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
\section{B}
\end{document}
```

### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. One more question, is it possible to make 1.1.1 not a subsection but something like a "enumerate" with items?

Comment: @sduplooy: You can redefine the labels of `enumerate` to include the section number as described in [Include section number in list number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/include-section-number-in-list-number).

Comment: In addition to the answer above, which is certainly great, one could add `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}` so that the numbering is in Roman number. Hope this is helpful for people.