# Include paragraph number in enumerate numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lists, enumerate

Similar to this question, [Include section number in list number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/include-section-number-in-list-number), I would like to prepend the paragraph number to the list item labels in a enumerate environment, e.g.

**Paragraph 1.** Some text

**1.1.** item 1 
**1.2.** item 2

**Paragraph 2.** Some more text

**2.1.** item 1 
**2.2.** item 2

etc...

I have tried to achieve this using

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\theparagraph.\arabic{enumi}}
```

but this ends up with the full sectioning number, e.g.

**3.1.2.0.0.1.** item 1 in ch.3, s.1, subs.2, para 1.

So there are two questions about this:

- how come the paragraph number always stays at 0?
- how do I get just the paragraph number?

---

**Edit**

I am using `\paragraph` commands. Here is the general structure of my section.

```
\section{foo}
text
\subsection{bar}
more text
\paragraph{baz} paragraph text
\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla
  \item blob
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{another} second para text
\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla again
  \item blob
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: what about `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic{enumi}}`

Comment: Are you using `\paragraph` commands? For the second question, instead of `\theparagraph` (which is typically defined in terms of the hierarchical section structure), use `\arabic{paragraph}`.

Comment: Your `\theparagraph` is strangely defined then, since it seems to always end with `0.0`...

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I tried using `\arabic{paragraph}`, which helps, but still displays 0 for the para number.

Comment: The `secnumdepth` decides whether relevant counters are increased or not. If the `article` standard value is used, then this is `3`, `paragraph`s however need a value of `4`. If it's still set to 3, the paragraph counter is fixed to 0. I assume, that your `\theparagraph` outputs some other counter value

Comment: @nik: What does `\show\theparagraph` reveal in your `.log`?

Comment: @Werner \show\theparagraph says: `> \theparagraph=\long macro:
->\thesubsubsection .\@arabic \c@paragraph .
l.250 \show\theparagraph`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, that works. However, I don't want subsubsections or paragraphs to actually be numbered. Maybe I'll just have to use a nested list instead of a list in a paragraph...

Comment: @nik: Your screenshot explicitly shows numbered paragraphs ;-) Please make a final decision on your design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `enumitem` package, here without changing the paragraph counter format, only the `enumi` label is prepended with `\arabic{paragraph}` in the `\setlist` command. This will be applied for all `enumerate` environments.

If the change should be local only, just say `\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic*}]` then.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic*}}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\paragraph{Some Paragraph}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item text text text
  \item text text text
\end{enumerate}

\paragraph{Some other paragraph}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item text text text
  \item text text text
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]